# Pointers on managing database with 4000 tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql

I'm in the middle of designing a software system storing data in about 4000 tables in Microsoft SQL Server 2008. Does anyone have any pointers to ease management of such a large number of tables?

Thanks!

P.S.: It's already normalized.

Comment: What problems are you having?  Most database scripts are already set up to handle multiple tables.

Comment: I'm curious to know what type of system uses 4000 tables too!

Comment: Dear God...  Are these all performing unique functions?

Comment: Sam: sp_foreachtable will be very handy I'm sure. I'm not really concerned about SQL Server's capabilities as much as the process of keeping it organized for people to understand. It's an ERP system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use declarative [Policy-Based Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510667.aspx) instead of managing individual tables.

Comment: Ooh... I like this.

Answer (score 3):

About the only suggestion I can offer is learn to love the filter icon in SSMS to make it easier to find the objects you are looking for.